# How auto forward messages from a channel to another channel using Python

Tags: python, telethon, forwarding

How do I auto forward messages instantly from a channel to another channel? I created an example but doesn't work.

This is my example:

```
    `from telethon import TelegramClient, events

    api_id = 99999999
    api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()

    @client.on(events.NewMessage)
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        chat = await event.get_chat()
        if chat.id == 'Horse Racing Daily Tips Premium':
            await client.forward_messages('Greyhounds Daily Tips Premium', event.message)

    with client:
        client.run_until_disconnected()`
```

I tried to send from my source channel "Horse Racing Daily Tips Premium" to my destination channel 'Greyhounds Daily Tips Premium'; I am new of Python and Telegram bot so I am not sure I did the correct way.
I already launched the bot from my prompt command line, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use event.forward_to()
like this:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.chat_id == 123456:
        await event.forward_to(987654)
```

or use client.forward_messages()
like this:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.chat_id == 123456:
        #await client.forward_messages(where you want to forward, messages id, from where)
        await client.forward_messages(98765, event.id, event.chat_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but where can I find the chat id for each channel?  Thanks

Comment: Ok, it's working! thanks! there is a way to manipulate the source message to delete some parts? thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1- `chat.id` is integer, you can't compare it to a string

```
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if not event.is_channel:
        return
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    if chat.title == 'Horse Racing Daily Tips Premium':
        await event.forward_to('Greyhounds Daily Tips Premium')
```

2- using string chat title to fetch or match is not reliable all the time if more than one chat has the same name, so prefer chat identifiers if it's private channel or usernames if it's public channel, but if it works for your case keep it.

Comment: It's not working, I got an error when I try to send a message

Comment: You would need to post the "error" for others to know what it is and how it could be fixed.